# Posting messages to external Javascript via mshtml

Tags: javascript, c++, mshtml

I am attempting to communicate with an externally linked javascript file from the DOM using mshtml.

I figured using postMessage found in IHTMLWindow6 would be the easiest way but I am not receiving the messages in my external javascript file.

Here is my C++ code that posts the message:

```
if (!htmlDocu->get_parentWindow(&htmlWin2) && htmlWin2)
{
    IHTMLWindow6 *              htmlWin6;
    if (!htmlWin2->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLWindow6, (void **)&htmlWin6) && htmlWin6)
    {
        VARIANT varBstr;
        VariantInit(&varBstr);
        varBstr.vt = VT_BSTR;
        varBstr.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"*");

        BSTR str1 = SysAllocString(L"the message");
        htmlWin6->postMessage(str1, varBstr);
        VariantClear(&varBstr);
        SysFreeString(str1);
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript code that should be receiving the message but is not:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    alert('got message');  /* Never happens. Why? */
    alert(event.origin);   /* Never happens. Why? */
    alert(event.data);   /* Never happens. Why? */
}, false );
```

I believe the error is in the C++ as I am able to send a message event inside of the javascript with no issues:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    alert('sending message');    
    window.postMessage("lalala", "*");
}, false);
```

Could anyone provide where I can find good C++ example of using postMessage() via IHTMLWindow6?